# Linear Combinations of a Dense Set

Tags: vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable locally convex space and $D\subseteq X$ be dense.  Then, is the set of all finite-linear combinations of $D$ equal to $X$?

That is, when is $\operatorname{span}(D) = cl(D)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to find dense linear subspaces $M$ of a normed linear space which are proper subsets of $X$. Example, $\ell^{1}$ is  a proper linear subspace of $\ell^{2}$ and it is dense. So the answer is NO.